# Copy response body which has content type as octet-stream using ADF

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, octet-stream

I am working with an API that sends the response as octet-stream. I am calling the API using Web activity in ADF. Now this response has to be saved in the ADLS file, could be either in csv or json format. Is there any possible way to do this.

I am not at all familiar with this octet-stream types, so any help regarding this would be appreciated.

Comment: can you share what you have tried and error if you are facing any?

Comment: I have used the web activity to hit the API, and i was expecting a file download - here is the doc - [link](https://api.qualtrics.com/41296b6f2e828-get-response-export-file), i dont get any error also, the output is application/octet-stream - like this
```PK  vncV               Top PC Client Survey 2021.jsoní}érÛÈ’î«`ôã,14öE®VÛ²-[¶d«»§;:Š@‘, E=q"æî¯y½y’›™€¤@TÚ’Ïe´Û–H µâË¥2¿üÏŒçÓ4Éy¾³ûÿÙüvîìî|ú]?øòòçà—sýèòZ?;ƒ•xíîäËŠ#Vp¸ÒÐý…f¿ÐµCÛ5Ý][ÿ.æIØ~·k›x<£(áiÚ`GL÷Ãš‡ßvOµ
U7Õ÷áªi–Žå7ºW†eÆ
‘&;»Ž>Ø‰Däý…_2¤YÈ{ZU}ÇÂ–——vŽ¾SÁ“âË‹÷,ÆÇ½J ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this myself, I figured out that the response was octet-stream because it was sending a zip file. So I saved the response using copy activity with HTTP linked service to ADLS as .zip output file and later used a copy activity again to extract that zip file into the ADLS store again using the compression type as zipdeflate, like how its usually done in ADF to extract.

[image: Source Dataset Settings]